# Can we trace all the Linux kernel functions using kprobes

Tags: c, debugging, linux-kernel, trace, kprobe

I read the below regarding kprobes:

> Kprobes allows you to install pre-handlers and post-handlers for any
>   kernel instruction as well as for function-entry and function-return
>   handlers

I am trying to register a kprobe for '_do_sys_open' function.

```
$ sudo cat /proc/kallsyms | grep 'do_sys_open'
ffffffff96ac0130 T do_sys_open
```

Wrote a basic code which registers the kprobe

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kprobes.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static struct kprobe kp;;
static char *name = "_do_sys_open";

static int pre_handler(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    return 0;
}

static void post_handler(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs,
             unsigned long flags)
{
}

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    /* set the handler functions */
    kp.pre_handler = pre_handler;
    kp.post_handler = post_handler;
    kp.symbol_name = name;
    return register_kprobe(&kp);
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
    unregister_kprobe(&kp);
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Loading this module fails with

```
Unknown symbol in module
```

Does this mean this function cannot be used with kprobes.

It is also not listed in the blacklist

```
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/kprobes/blacklist | grep '_do_sys_open'
```

Comment: What's your kernel's version? What's your CPU architecture?

Comment: Linux Kernel version 5.2, CPU Architecture:x86_64

Comment: I might be missing something, but why do you have an underscore at the beginning of the symbol's name? Don't you want to trace `do_sys_open`?

Comment: Was that the issue or just a typo?

Comment: No, some functions may not be traceable. It depends on compiler optimizations, on specifics of those functions, etc.

Comment: @Tsyvarev "Unknown symbol in module" is printed when the module insertion fails with an `ENOENT` error. That's not necessarily due to dynamic linking errors. It could be due to the module init function returning `-ENOENT` (which is likely if `register_kprobe` is being given a non-existant symbol name!).

Comment: @IanAbbott: Yes, it is my fault - didn't think about `register_kprobe` return value.

Comment: We can't help without any more details, currently it seems like the issue is just a typo. Anyway, make sure to not `kprobe` functions that are marked as `NOKPROBE_SYMBOL`.